# how to add update screen on older version of the app to download the latest version in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have just released an update for react native android app, the update is successful but I want to add an update screen on the older version of the app (users having old version) to download the latest version of the app. How can I achieve that any leads?

Comment: If it's a custom update screen i don't think you can, you should've added that functionality priory to that app release. Other options are using push notifications to notify old users, or if using [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com), they have functionality for in app alerts

Comment: If I want to add a custom update screen to show in older versions, how can I add the functionality?